# ImageResizer image doesn't anchor when too small to resize

Tags: asp.net, webforms, imageresizer

Been using ImageResizer quite effectively on my projects but just ran into an issue.

I have an img element that can have it's src change frequently but I always have the same dimensions of width and height to resize, along with the anchor=middleleft.

However, I don't want to upscale, so sometimes an image that is too small will be placed there and it won't anchor as desired.

Does anyone know a way to allow the anchor to still work when the image is too small to resize it? Or am I just going to have to have a fallback of css left alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`scale=canvas`](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/docs/basics). This ensures the returned image is exactly the requested size, and adds padding as required.